# Gstreamer Bad plugins opencv: WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "opencvtextoverlay"

Tags: linux, opencv, ubuntu, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I have installed GStreamer on my ubuntu 18.04 using

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
```

from the guide here. https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c

when I try to use the opencvtextoverlay plugin in the bad plugins I get the next error `WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "opencvtextoverlay"`

example pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=1.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux ! queue ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! opencvtextoverlay text="test" ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! autovideosink
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin you are trying to use(`opencvtextoverlay`) is from OpenCV, for this reason is that you need to install the following library:

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-opencv
```

Then you can check if it exists with the following command:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 opencvtextoverlay
```

Your pipeline should work fine now.